# What's the proper way to have one MySQL row access many indexes from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a "`PRODUCTS`" table like so:

```
------------------
ID     NAME
------------------
1     tomato
2     lettuce
3     bacon
4     bread
5     mayonnaise
6     tuna
------------------
```

And in my other table "`PEOPLE`", I would like to associate 1 person with many products...but I don't know how many.

How I have been doing it is to put all the ID's of products in a single field for that person as numbers separated by spaces (3 5 2 6), then exploding into an array, then looping through the array and grabbing each product with a query WHERE id= x.

I'm sure this has been done many other times (like a single user in Facebook having many friends...all with their own ID's). Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) AKA link table.

Comment: Read about database normalization and many-to-many relations

Comment: Excellent. Thanks...I have some learning to do.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way is via [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Tables:

- products (id, product_name)
- people (id, person_name)
- people_products (id, product_id, person_id)

In this way you can have many-to-many relationships.

Then, for example, to get a complete listing of each person and their associated products, you could use this query:

```
SELECT person_name, product_name FROM people_products 
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = people_products.product_id 
INNER JOIN people ON people.id = people_products.person_id;
```

Comment: And then you can write queries like to suggest to people like 5 out of 10 people who eats tomato also eats bacon and so on and that will just be fun.

Answer (score 1):

setup a new table that links people ids to product ids.

eg table "PeopleProducts"

```
--------------------------
id  peopleId  productId
--------------------------
1     3        1
2     3        4
3     2        1
```

etc.

Then use a sql join to get products associated with a specific people Id, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM PeopleProducts LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.ID = PeopleProducts.productId WHERE PeopleProducts.peopleId = 3
```